# Ссылочные типы Java

Tags: java

Я начал учить Java и не могу понять один момент. Просматривая очередной видеоурок я услышал, что "*При создании переменной одного из ссылочных типов происходит создание ячейки памяти, содержащей ссылку на произвольный объект в памяти. Когда мы присваиваем значение этой ссылочной переменной в другую переменную, происходит копирование ссылки и мы получаем вторую ссылку, указывающую на тот же объект*"

Далее сказано, что "*Если объект модифицировать через вторую ссылку, то **изменения будут видны и через первую ссылку, потому что это тот же самый объект***"

Я это понял так, что в памяти есть один и тот же объект, на который могут ссылаться несколько переменных. Соответственно при изменении одной переменной, ссылающейся на данный объект, будут изменены и значения всех других переменных, ссылающихся на этот же объект

Решив проверить это опытным путем я тут же написал короткий код:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "Hello";
    String s2 = s1;

    s2 += "!";

    System.out.println("s1 = " + s1 + "\n" + "s2 = " + s2);

    }
}
```

Сначала я создая переменную `s1` ссылочного типа `String` и присваиваю ей произвольное значение. После этого, создаю новую переменную `s2` и приравниваю ее к `s1`. Как я понял, должно происходить копирование ссылки, и в итоге обе переменные должны ссылаться на один и тот же объект строки в памяти. Соответственно, при изменении этого объекта в памяти через одну переменную, изменения должны быть видны и через другую, но этого не происходит - ниже представлен вывод этой программы

```
>>> s1 = Hello
>>> s2 = Hello!
```

Почему изменение объекта, на который ссылается `s1` не привело к изменению объекта, на который ссылается `s2`, учитывая, что они должны ссылаться на один и тот же объект в памяти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объекты типа String в Java - неизменяемы. Когда вы вносите изменение в объект типа String с помощью одного из методов этого класса или с помощью конкатенации (в вашем случае - для изменения строки используется конкатенация: s2 += "!";) - тогда создается **НОВЫЙ** объект класса String который будет представлять собой (по содержанию символов) старую строку с внесенными изменениями. В строке s2 += "!"; вы как раз создаете ещё одну строку и присваиваете переменной s2 ссылку на эту новую строку. При этом ссылка s1 попрежнему ссылается на объект строки созданный вами раннее.

Попробуйте провести ваш маленький эксперимент с типом StringBuilder (этот тип данных представляет собой как раз таки изменяемую строку).

Comment: Извините. Понял и ниже обобщил

Answer (score 1):

Объект `String` является неизменяемым. Несмотря на то, что переменные типа `String` являются ссылочными, при их изменении создается новый объект и новая переменная по ссылке указывает уже на него(а не на тот объект, который был взят для изменения).

### Типы переменных

---

#### Примитивные и ссылочные

Примитивные типы Java не являются объектами. К ним относятся:

`boolean` - булев тип, может иметь значения true или false

`byte` - 8-разрядное целое число

`short` - 16-разрядное целое число

`int` - 32-разрядное целое число

`long` - 64-разрядное целое число

`char` - 16-разрядное беззнаковое целое, представляющее собой символ UTF-16 (буквы и цифры)

`float` - 32-разрядное число в формате IEEE 754 с плавающей точкой

`double` - 64-разрядное число в формате IEEE 754 с плавающей точкой

***Все остальные типы являются ссылочными.***
Подробнее [здесь](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/types.php)

---

#### Изменяемые и неизменяемые

Тип `String` неизменяемый. При попытке изменения значения переменных этого типа, в памяти будет создаваться новый объект

Изменяемым типом является к примеру `ArrayList` или `StringBuilder`, использующийся ниже в примере

Подробнее [здесь](https://coderwall.com/p/80it1w/immutable-vs-mutable-java)

---

Желаемое поведение программы достигается, при использовании ссылочных, изменяемых типов(`String` - ссылочный, неизменяемый)

Перепишем программу с использованием изменяемого аналога `String` - `StringBuilder`:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Создаём изменяемый объект типа `StringBuilder`
    StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder("Hello");
    // s2 - ссылка на s1
    StringBuilder s2 = s1;

    // `StringBuilder` - изменяемый,
    //  поэтому нового объекта не создается
    s2.append("!");

    // При изменении объекта, изменились значения
    // и всех ссылающихся на него переменных
    System.out.println("s1 = " + s1 + "\n" + "s2 = " + s2);

    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
>>> s1 = Hello!
>>> s2 = Hello!
```

Подробнее про `StringBuilder` [здесь](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/7.3.php)